# Screen capturing via code

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, motion-capture, viewlayers, screencast

I created FBX and FLT files with textures and polygons and, thanks to awesome Blender, I turned it into a very nice simulator. My goal is to add some drawings/markers/polygons, based on my location in real-time. This is by using my external function and minimal understanding and interaction with Blender.

The external function gets the location (6DoF), and returns the drawing layer.
The simpleset solution I have in mind is to write a function that:

a) Calls the external function with current location to get the drawing.

b) Captures the current image screen that Blender displays

c) Pastes the drawing on this image

d) Outputs the updated screen, say, in another window.

My questions:

1. For step (b), how can I save the current screen to a file automatically (without using the GUI or human in the loop)?
2. Is there a simple way to implement (b), (c) and even (d) in memory, without files?
3. Is there a better solution, instead of this workaround, that a good programmer but totally novice in Blender like me can learn and implement in few days of works?

Thanks in advance

Danny